# Bash: Passing a variable into a script that has spaces

Tags: bash

I currently have a bash script. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    sendcommand)
        do X with $2
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

How would I send all of command `this command with spaces` into $2 without `command` acting as $3, `with` as $4 and so on? Is there something like PHP or Javascript's encodeURI for bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have to call your script with the second argument in quotes too

```
./scriptname sendcommand "command with spaces"
```

Your script should look like this

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    sendcommand)
        something "$2"
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose it in double quotes:

```
do_X_with "$2"
```

The double quotes preserve the internal spacing on the variable, including newlines if they are in the value in the first place.  Indeed, it is important to understand the uses of double quotes with `"$@"` and `"$*"` too, not to mention when using `bash` arrays.

You can't easily have a command called `do` because the shell uses `do` as a keyword in its loop structure.  To invoke it, you would have to specify a path to the command, such as `./do` or `$HOME/bin/do`.

---

> But $2 is "this" and the OP wants it to be "this command with spaces".

OK.  We need to review command line invocations and desired behaviours.  Let's assume that the script being executed is called `script`.  Further, that command being executed is `othercommand` (can't use `command`; that is a standard command).

Possible invocations include:

- `script sendcommand "this command with spaces"`
- `script sendcommand 'this command with spaces'`
- `script sendcommand  this command with spaces`

The single-quote and double-quote invocations are equivalent in this example.  They wouldn't be equivalent if there were variables to be expanded or commands to be invoked inside the argument lists.

It is possible to write `script` to handle all three cases:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    sendcommand)
        shift
        othercommand "$*"
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

Suppose that the invocation encloses the arguments in quotes.  The `shift` command removes `$1` from the argument list and renumbers the remaining (single) argument as `$1`.  It then invokes `othercommand` with a single string argument consisting of the contents of the arguments concatenated together.  If there were several arguments, the contents would be separated by a single 'space' (first character of `$IFS`).

Suppose that the invocation does not enclose the arguments in quotes.  The `shift` command still removes `$1` (the `sendcommand`) from the argument list, and then space separates the remaining arguments as a single argument.

In all three cases, the `othercommand` sees a single argument that consists of `"this command with spaces"` (where the program does not see the double quotes, of course).

Comment: But `$2` is "this" and the OP wants it to be "this command with spaces". I think "do" is a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use double quotes:

```
do X with "$2"
```

Comment: But `$2` is "this" and the OP wants it to be "this command with spaces".